# How can I construct a solution for this system of many inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let there be types $\omega\in\{0,1\}^n$ drawn according to some probability distribution. Suppose that these types are relayed through some imperfect message service. Specifically, any type $\omega$'s message, $m$, is always the product of some garbling so that $m\in\{0,1\}^n$, but $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i = k$. So there are $\binom{n}{k}$ different messages. A type $\omega$ will send message $m$ with probability $p_m^\omega$. I'd like to construct these distributions $p^\omega$ for each $\omega$ so that the message is "believed" according to a cost-weighted error. If $\omega_i=1$ and $m_i=0$, then the cost is 1. If $\omega_i=0$ and $m_i=1$, then the cost is $c$. Insofar as we want to minimize error, I think it's obvious that for any type $\omega$ it should send a message where $m_i=\omega_i$ when $\omega_i=1$, but for types where $\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i>k$, then some ones must be turned off so to speak. Similarly, we have to turn on some false ones for types $\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i<k$. Then, I think the problem is finding a distribution $p^\omega$ across messages for each $\omega$ so that for any $m$,

$$\sum_{\omega\in \{\omega:\sum_i^n\omega_i<k\}} c(k-\sum_i\omega_i )\Pr(\omega)p_m^\omega + \sum_{\omega\in \{\omega:\sum_i^n\omega_i\geq k\}} (\sum_i\omega_i-k)\Pr(\omega)p_m^\omega$$ $$\leq \sum_{\Omega}\Pr(\omega)p_m^\omega(\sum_i\omega_i) .$$

This inequality says that the cost of errors made from believing $\omega_i=m_i$ when $\omega_i=0$ and $m_i=1$ is less than the number of errors made from disregarding the message and believing every $\omega_i=0$.
I think we can always find these $p^\omega$s whenever $\Pr(\sum_i^n\omega_i < k)\leq \frac{1}{c+1}$, but I don't believe this is necessary and I don't see how to actually construct the distributions to guarantee the inequality above.

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if anything is unclear.

Example: Let $n=3$, $c=1$, and $\Pr(\omega_i=1)=.4$, i.i.d. Then for $k=2$, we can have $p^{(0,1,1)}_{(0,1,1)}=1$,$p^{(1,0,1)}_{(1,0,1)}=1$, and $p^{(1,1,0)}_{(1,1,0)}=1$. Then for the low types, set $p^{(1,0,0)}_{(1,1,0)}=p^{(1,0,0)}_{(1,0,1)}=1/2$. Similarly, set $p^{(0,1,0)}_{(1,1,0)}=p^{(0,1,0)}_{(0,1,1)}=1/2$ and set $p^{(0,0,1)}_{(0,1,1)}=p^{(0,0,1)}_{(1,0,1)}=1/2$. Finally, let the remaining types, $\omega=(1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,0)$ have $p^\omega_{(0,1,1)}=1$. I think all of the coniditions are met, yet $\Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n\omega<2)=0.648$ is not less than $1/2=\frac{1}{c+1}$.

Comment: "A type $ω$ will send message $m$ with probability p^ω_m" The type is selected at random, and also for each selected type, the message is (can) be produced by some random rule?

Comment: Yes, the type is random, but you can imagine that the $p^\omega_m$ is not. Instead, consider it as something that is chosen and fixed, and we are trying to find one such $p^\omega$ satisfying the given conditions.

Comment: *"Let there be types $\omega \in \{0,1\}^n$ drawn according to some probability distribution."* Is this probability distribution known? That is, can the construction of the distributions $p^\omega$ be dependent on the distribution of the $\omega$? $\tag*{}$ Also, are the types all of $\{0,1\}^n$ or just a subset of $\{0,1\}^n$? (That is, are there always more types than messages when $n \ge 1$?)

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. And to your second question, it could be anything. As in, the types are all of $\{0,1\}^n$, but we can put probability zero on some if we like. Doing that feels like cheating, but perhaps it will help.

Comment: Oh, can the distribution on the types be chosen? In that case, you can take the distribution on the types to be $\Pr(\omega) = \begin{cases}1/\binom{n}{k} & \text{if $\omega$ has $k$ $1$s} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, then let $p^\omega_m = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $\omega = m$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. That will give you total cost $0$, as the messages will experience no garbling. That seems against the spirit of the question though, so maybe that's not what you meant.

Comment: I think the extension from here is simply to impose that $\Pr(\omega)=\Pr(\omega')$ if $\omega,\omega'$ have the same number of $1$s. Let $\omega^k$ be a type with $k$ $1$s. Then any type $\omega$ with $\sum_i \omega_i<k$ uniformly imitates all types $\omega^k$ such that $\omega^k \geq \omega$. The same goes "from above." For types $\omega$ with $\sum_i \omega_i>k$ and types $\omega^k\leq \omega$, then $p^\omega$ is a uniform distribution over all such $\omega^k$.

Comment: Why is this in precalculus?